# Trying to prevent a value from resetting

Tags: html, random

I'm trying to make a thing for an assignment and I need to make it so basically two "dots" race and they move a random distance from 1-3. I have the random generator working but each time I press the button to advance the "dots" the value of how far they should be keeps resetting and I can't figure out how to fix it, and I can't get anything else to work if the values aren't declared as zero, and that's the problem because that's what is causing the values to reset each time I press the button. If someone could help me it would be greatly appreciated.

(This is what I have for my code, this is in HTML btw)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> Dot Race </title>

  <h1> Dot Race </h1>

    <body>

    <script>

    function dotAdvance()
    {

     var dot1F = 0, dot2F = 0;

     dot1A =Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
     dot2A =Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
     
    if(dot1A == 0)
    {
     
    }
    else if(dot1A == 1)
    {
     dot1F++;
    }
    else if(dot1A == 2)
    {
     dot1F++;
     dot1F++;
    }
    else
    {
     dot1F++;
     dot1F++;
     dot1F++;
    }

    if(dot2A == 0)
    {
     
    }
    else if(dot2A == 1)
    {
     dot2F++;
    }
    else if(dot2A == 2)
    {
     dot2F++;
     dot2F++;
    }
    else
    {
     dot2F++;
     dot2F++;
     dot2F++;
    }

    goal= parseFloat(document.getElementById('goalDistance').value);    
    
       if(dot1F >= goal && dot2F >= goal)
        {
          alert("Test: Tie");
        }
        else if(dot1F >= goal)
        {
          alert("Test: Dot 1");
        }
        else if(dot2F >= goal)
        {
          alert("Test: Dot 2");
        }
    
     document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = "Test:" + dot1F + "  Test2:" + dot2F;

    }

    </script>


Enter Goal Distance: <input type="text" id="goalDistance" size=12 value="">

<button onclick="">Reset Race</button>
<button onclick="dotAdvance()">Take a Step</button>

<hr>

<div id="outputDiv"></div>
<body>
</html>
``
```

Comment: why don't you just do `dot1F += dot1A`?  those `if` statements with `dot1F++`'s in look very awkward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call the function dotAdvance the variables dot1F and dot2F are reset. You should try to take them out from the function.

Comment: Is there a specific place I should be putting them? I've tried moving them out of the function several times but they don't seem to work when I do. (Edit: I just figured it out, thank you for your help man, I appreciate it.)